# Redirect to action in another controller from LoginPartialView

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have defined the following partial view _LoginPartialView.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> @User.Identity.GetUserName()<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Zarządzaj kontem", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Edytuj dane osobowe", "Edit", "Users", new { id=User.Identity.GetUserId()})</li>
                <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    }
}
```

When I click on "Edytuj dane osobowe", it redirects me to default route

```
http://localhost:xxxxx/Home/Edit?Length=5
```

I defined UsersController with method Edit, which looks like this

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            User user = repository.GetUserById(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(user);
        }
```

When I type manually the url with parameter id, it displays me the proper page. What is the reason of that strange redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try to replace

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Edytuj dane osobowe", "Edit", "Users", new { id=User.Identity.GetUserId()})</li>
```

with :

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Edytuj dane osobowe", "Edit", "Users", new { id=User.Identity.GetUserId()}, null)</li>
```